# Make numerous table changes that appear to occur simultaneously

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, oracle11g

Every so many hours I need to delete several thousand records in a table and then immediately insert several thousand records to replace the deleted records. There are applications that occasionally read this data. I don't want these apps to do a table read and get some of the old records along with some of the new, and I don't want these apps to ever read before all records have been inserted.

I want to make the deletions and inserts from my C# code. I would combine them into a single "Begin" and "End" block and send it all at once to Oracle...except it could be 100k plus in size. Which seems too large. So it seems that running multiple statements within a for next loop is my best choice. But it seems that would cause my table to have part old data and part new data while the loop is running. That is what I need to avoid.

How can I perform the deletions and subsequent insertions so they appear to occur simultaneously to applications reading the table, and hence avoid the aforementioned undesired issues?

Comment: One huge transaction?

Comment: First of all do that in SP not in C# code and a transaction seems to correct approach...you can commit transaction when deletion and insertion is done

Comment: Have you timed your 100k plus send to see how long it takes?

Comment: Is a 100k plus size query considered good practice? Isn't that too large?

Comment: @JoeGayetty You could probably insert the new rows into a temp table from code, then insert/merge from that table into the main table inside a transaction.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Ok, that makes sense! Never thought of that! So I could put the thousand new rows into "temptable" using a loop, then run "delete from mytable where..." and "insert into mytable ( select * from temptable)" in one code block. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @JoeGayetty Yes, that should shorten the time you spend in a transaction considerably.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Awesome. I will give that a try. If you want to post your comment as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing a quick switch is to insert the data into a temp table, start a transaction and do an `INSERT` or [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) from that table to the main table.

That way, the time sensitive operation is done by the RDBMS engine itself, and the non time sensitive insertion of data into the temp table will not affect the switchover time.

Comment: Excellent suggestion! This seems better than trying to create a 100k+ sized single Begin/End block. This is the solution I plan to use. Thanks!